# Defining hypotenuse of a triangle in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

I am working on an assignment in which we are given a (my_x,my_y) coordinate and we have to tell whether this coordinate lies in the free space or inside an obstacle.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, from the picture, I have to tell whether a certain point lies among any of the obstacle.

Checking for out of boundary is easy and simple.
Similarly I check for circle as (pseudo code):

> if sqrt((my_x-5)^2+(my_y-3.5)^2) <= 0.5
>
> this means it is inside circle.
>
> if ((my_x >= 3.5 || my_x <= 6.5) && ((my_y >= 5 || my_y <= 6)
>
> this means it is inside rectangle.

However I am stuck for the triangle case. The main reason is that my_x and my_y are of decimal type and can take any value suppose up to 2 decimal figures. Now one was is to have several if conditions and then check each.

I want to know is there is some better algorithm to define the triangle may be using equations and what it might be.

Comment: Use barycentric coordinates for the 2D case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_%28mathematics%29#Determining_whether_a_point_is_inside_a_triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you the concept of `vector products` to find if a point is inside a triangle or not :-

suppose point is `(x,y)` which you need to check. `(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)` are three vertices of the triangle. then each triple `((x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x,y)),((x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x,y)),((x3,y3),(x1,y1),(x,y))` are of same sign.

```
vector product of (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x,y)

vp = (x-x2)*(y1-y2) - (y-y2)*(x1-x2)
```

Hence using same equation for all triples :-

```
sign1 = sign((x-x2)*(y1-y2) - (y-y2)*(x1-x2))
sign2 = sign((x-x3)*(y2-y3) - (y-y3)*(x2-x3))
sign3 = sign((x-x1)*(y3-y1) - (y-y1)*(x3-x1))


if(sign1==sign2==sign3) { //inside

       return(true);

}

else return(false)      // outside
```

Comment: is the sign function a standard one? or i will have to make my own?

Comment: it is standard sign function